# RDP Printer not Showing ( Lubuntu to Windows Server 2008 r2)

Tags: sql-server-2008, printing, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to ubuntu...

I'm currently running Lubuntu latest version on my PC and RDP to windows server 2008 r2 works pretty well. But I can't detect any local printer on the network. I'm using Remmina 1.1.0 .
I have tried enable local sound which in some forums are the problem. But still doesn't work for me.

If I run RDP windows 7 to windows server 2008 R2, all printers on network are detected well.

Is there any packages to be installed to fix this problem? Please help... Thankyou